# SQL group by with an opration like TRUE/FALSE logic from other columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to use `group by`to arrange identical data into groups. In addition, i want to have a second column that has a logic based on the content of other columns. For example, in table below, i group by with column a and add a second column with True value only if all identical has cond=True

```
       a     cond
0  cust1     True
1  cust1     True
2  cust1    False
3  cust2     True
4  cust2     True
5  cust3     True
6  cust3     True
7  cust3     True
8  cust4     True
9  cust4    False
```

result in

```
       a     cond
0  cust1    False
1  cust2     True
2  cust3     True
3  cust4    False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select   a
        ,min(cond) as cond
from     t
group by a
```

| a | cond |
| --- | --- |
| cust1 | False |
| cust2 | True |
| cust3 | True |
| cust4 | False |